# Cant seem to find the right regex for "Backup-YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: bash, linux-mint

I have to find directories with such pattern **Backup-YYYY-MM-DD**.

I've tested this regex online and it should work, but I'm doing something wrong.

```bsh
find $HOME -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^Backup-[0-9]{4,}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

I've created a directory named **Backup-1999-10-05** in home/user.
The command doesn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-regex` is a *whole path match*. Try instead

```
-regex '.*/Backup-[0-9]{4,}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
```